# Make CSS background image continuously change jQuery to mimic flashing

Tags: jquery, css, svg, background-image, addclass

I'm looking to continuously loop through a set of background images that are the same but change colour to mimic a sort of colour change effect (I've tried with embedded SVG fills and it wont work as needed)

Initial idea was to add and remove classes that contain the background image urls. But I'm not really sure how to go about it? Can loop through on .click function but I need it to happen continuously from page load.

Any help much appreciated. Big thanks

HTML:

```
<h1>Lets make 
    <span class="container--pop">
          <span class="container--pop__container">
                <span class="text--highlight text--highlight-red">this</span>
          </span>
     </span>
change background.
</h1>
```

CSS:

```
.text--highlight-red {
    background:url('../images/sprites/brush-stroke.svg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    height: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.3em 0.8em 0.5em 0.5em;
}

.text--highlight-green {
    background:url('../images/sprites/brush-stroke-green.svg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    height: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.3em 0.8em 0.5em 0.5em;
}

.text--highlight-orange {
    background:url('../images/sprites/brush-stroke-orange.svg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    height: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.3em 0.8em 0.5em 0.5em;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.text--highlight').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('text--highlight-red'))
        {
            $(this).addClass('text--highlight-green').removeClass('text--highlight-red');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).addClass('text--highlight-orange').removeClass('text--highlight-green');
        }
    });
```

Comment: look into `setInterval()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put colors in one array and use modulus operator `%` with `setInterval` to loop through that array.

```js
var colors = ['green', 'red', 'yellow', 'blue'];

(function() {
  var i = 0;
  function changeBg() {
    $('div').css('background-color', colors[i]);
    i = (i+1) % colors.length;
  }

  setInterval(changeBg, 1000);
})();
```

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: This is great, but how would I pass how many times to loop this array (in hindsight having it continuously doing this is bad!) haha Thank you

Comment: AWESOME. I just updated the if statement as it needs curlys and a missing semi-colon but all magic - thank you all makes sense :) `(function() {
      var i = 0;
      function changeBg() {
        //console.log( "change my colours" );
        $('.text--highlight').css('background-image', colors[i]);
        if(counter < 8) { i = (i+1) % colors.length;
        counter++; }
      }

      setInterval(changeBg, 300);
    })();`

Answer (score 3):

CSS3 solution:

Use CSS3 animation to change `background-color` at specific intervals.

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: changeColor;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes changeColor {
    0%   {background-color:red;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow;}
    50%  {background-color:blue;}
    75%  {background-color:green;}
    100% {background-color:red;}
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Roy's solution is a great start, however the question is asking for changing the color of an image, not the background color. Since the OP specifically said that the images are the same and she is trying to achieve a color change effect, I propose using a partially transparent overlay. I used the before pseudo element along with Roy's technique to do it in [this codepen](http://codepen.io/developering/pen/vGWoYp).

A couple things to note:

1. The container must be position relative so that the absolutely positioned overlay will stay within the bounds of the container.
2. Any children that need to show on top of the overlay need to also be position relative. If you remove the position relative from the h1, you will see that it then shows behind the overlay.

And here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>This is on top of the overlay</h1>
</div>


.container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/image_output/cats-q-c-640-480-1.jpg') no-repeat;
}
.container:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: .3;

  background-color: red;
  animation-name: changeColor;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: arial;
}

@keyframes changeColor {
    0%   {background-color:red;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow;}
    50%  {background-color:blue;}
    75%  {background-color:green;}
    100% {background-color:red;}
}
```